# A connected open set is path connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

My analysis course states that a connected open set is path connected but I haven't been able to prove it.
Here we consider a subset of the field of complex number but I suppose it works for a general topological space.
Cheers

Comment: It doesn't work for arbitrary topological spaces, but it works for locally path-connected spaces.

Comment: The proof is here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Connected_Open_Subset_of_Euclidean_Space_is_Path-Connected

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Show that if $U$ is an open set in a *normed space*, then for each $x \in U$ the set of points that are path-connected to $x$ is open and closed (relative to $U$).